# Prevent Array Decay for overloaded functions taking const char* or const char(&)[]

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

Given the following class

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    void DoSomething(const T* str) {

    }

    template<size_t N>
    void DoSomething(const T(&str)[N]) {

    }
};
```

Is there a way to prevent my arrays from 'decaying' to the `(const char*)` overload?

The function is invoked in the following fashion but it seems to take preference to the non-templated function.

```
MyClass m<char>;
m.DoSomething("Beep Boop");
```

I've found I can invoke the templated function by explicitly providing a value for the templated argument. I would like to not do this if possible.

```
MyClass m<char>;
m.DoSomething<10>("Beep Boop");
```

Via possible duplicate link I solve this by changing the non-templated method to the following signature:

```
template<typename = std::enable_if< std::is_convertible<const T*, T const*>, {} >>
void DoSomething(const T* str) {

}
```

Comment: @StoryTeller at first glance, looks like dupe...

Comment: @EdgarRokyan - Yeah, I just got to the workaround